# Compiling OSGeo/proj.4 return [install-projHEADERS] Error 1

Tags: 14.04, compiling, make

Compiling OSGeo/proj.4 return [install-projHEADERS] Error 1

I'm installing OSGeo/proj.4 in Ubuntu 14, (cloned from https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4), following the guide.

proj.4 version currently cloned is 6.2.0 , the same happens with version 6.1.0 . Version 5.2.0. compile properly.

`libsqlite3-dev` and `sqlite3` are installed.

The command

```
./autogen.sh
```

return

```
Running aclocal
Running autoheader
Running libtoolize
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, `.'.
libtoolize: copying file `./ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, `m4'.
libtoolize: copying file `m4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
Running automake
Running autoconf
======================================
Now you are ready to run './configure'
======================================
```

So

```
CFLAGS=-fPIC ./configure --prefix=/software/proj.4 --enable-shared=no
```

return

```
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking whether build environment is sane... yes
    checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
    checking for gawk... no
    checking for mawk... mawk
    checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
    checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables... 
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
    checking for style of include used by make... GNU
    checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
    checking for g++... g++
    checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
    checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
    checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
    checking whether g++ supports C++11 features by default... no
    checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with -std=c++11... yes
    checking whether ln -s works... yes
    checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
    checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking how to print strings... printf
    checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
    checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
    checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
    checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
    checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
    checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
    checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
    checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
    checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
    checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
    checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
    checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
    checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
    checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
    checking for objdump... objdump
    checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
    checking for dlltool... no
    checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
    checking for ar... ar
    checking for archiver @FILE support... @
    checking for strip... strip
    checking for ranlib... ranlib
    checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
    checking for sysroot... no
    checking for mt... mt
    checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
    checking for ANSI C header files... yes
    checking for sys/types.h... yes
    checking for sys/stat.h... yes
    checking for stdlib.h... yes
    checking for string.h... yes
    checking for memory.h... yes
    checking for strings.h... yes
    checking for inttypes.h... yes
    checking for stdint.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... yes
    checking for dlfcn.h... yes
    checking for objdir... .libs
    checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
    checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
    checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
    checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
    checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
    checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
    checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
    checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
    checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build shared libraries... no
    checking whether to build static libraries... yes
    checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -std=c++11 -E
    checking for ld used by g++ -std=c++11... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
    checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
    checking whether the g++ -std=c++11 linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking for g++ -std=c++11 option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
    checking if g++ -std=c++11 PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
    checking if g++ -std=c++11 static flag -static works... yes
    checking if g++ -std=c++11 supports -c -o file.o... yes
    checking if g++ -std=c++11 supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
    checking whether the g++ -std=c++11 linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
    checking C_WFLAGS for maximum warnings... -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    checking CXX_WFLAGS for maximum warnings... -Wall
    checking whether C compiler accepts -Werror -we10006... no
    checking whether C compiler accepts -diag-disable 188,1684,2259,2304,3280,11074,11076... no
    checking whether C compiler accepts -Wextra... yes
    checking whether C compiler accepts -Winit-self... yes
    checking whether C compiler accepts -Wunused-parameter... yes
    checking whether C compiler accepts -Wmissing-prototypes... yes
    checking whether C compiler accepts -Wmissing-declarations... yes
    checking whether C compiler accepts -Wformat... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wno-format-nonliteral... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wshorten-64-to-32... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wlogical-op... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wshadow... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Werror=vla... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Werror=declaration-after-statement... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wdate-time... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wnull-dereference... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wduplicated-cond... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wextra-semi... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wno-sign-compare... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wcomma... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wfloat-conversion... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wdocumentation -Wno-documentation-deprecated-sync... no
checking if -std=gnu89 can be enabled... yes
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wunused-private-field... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wmissing-prototypes... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wmissing-declarations... yes
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wnon-virtual-dtor... yes
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wold-style-cast... yes
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Weffc++... yes
checking if -Weffc++ should be enabled... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Woverloaded-virtual... yes
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wweak-vtables... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wdeprecated... yes
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wabstract-vbase-init... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Winconsistent-missing-destructor-override... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -fno-operator-names... yes
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant... yes
checking to enable LTO (link time optimization) build... no
checking for exp in -lm... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -fp-model precise... no
checking for C99 math functions... yes
checking for library containing sqrt... none required
checking for localeconv... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking jni.h usability... no
checking jni.h presence... no
checking for jni.h... no
checking whether to enable Java/JNI support... disabled
checking for mutexes... checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for pthread_mutexattr_settype in -lpthread... yes
checking whether PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE is declared... yes
enabled, pthread
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for SQLITE3... yes
checking for sqlite3... yes
using internal GTest.
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating cmake/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating include/Makefile
config.status: creating include/proj/Makefile
config.status: creating include/proj/internal/Makefile
config.status: creating test/Makefile
config.status: creating test/cli/Makefile
config.status: creating test/gie/Makefile
config.status: creating test/gigs/Makefile
config.status: creating test/unit/Makefile
config.status: creating man/Makefile
config.status: creating man/man1/Makefile
config.status: creating man/man3/Makefile
config.status: creating data/Makefile
config.status: creating jniwrap/Makefile
config.status: creating jniwrap/org.osgeo.proj/Makefile
config.status: creating jniwrap/org.osgeo.proj/org/Makefile
config.status: creating jniwrap/org.osgeo.proj/org/proj4/Makefile
config.status: creating test/googletest/Makefile
config.status: creating test/googletest/include/Makefile
config.status: creating test/googletest/include/gtest/Makefile
config.status: creating test/googletest/include/gtest/internal/Makefile
config.status: creating test/googletest/include/gtest/internal/custom/Makefile
config.status: creating test/googletest/src/Makefile
config.status: creating proj.pc
config.status: WARNING:  'proj.pc.in' seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
config.status: creating src/proj_config.h
config.status: src/proj_config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
```

then `make`

```
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/bash /software/proj.4/missing aclocal-1.14 -I m4
 cd . && /bin/bash /software/proj.4/missing automake-1.14 --gnu
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/bash /software/proj.4/missing autoconf
/bin/bash ./config.status --recheck
running CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/bash /bin/bash ./configure --prefix=/software/proj.4 --enable-shared=no CFLAGS=-fPIC --no-create --no-recursion
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features by default... no
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with -std=c++11... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 3458764513820540925
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... no
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -std=c++11 -E
checking for ld used by g++ -std=c++11... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ -std=c++11 linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ -std=c++11 option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ -std=c++11 PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ -std=c++11 static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ -std=c++11 supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ -std=c++11 supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ -std=c++11 linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking C_WFLAGS for maximum warnings... -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement
checking CXX_WFLAGS for maximum warnings... -Wall
checking whether C compiler accepts -Werror -we10006... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -diag-disable 188,1684,2259,2304,3280,11074,11076... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wextra... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Winit-self... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wunused-parameter... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wmissing-prototypes... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wmissing-declarations... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wformat... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wno-format-nonliteral... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wshorten-64-to-32... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wlogical-op... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wshadow... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Werror=vla... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Werror=declaration-after-statement... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wdate-time... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wnull-dereference... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wduplicated-cond... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wextra-semi... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wno-sign-compare... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wcomma... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wfloat-conversion... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wdocumentation -Wno-documentation-deprecated-sync... no
checking if -std=gnu89 can be enabled... yes
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wunused-private-field... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wmissing-prototypes... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wmissing-declarations... yes
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wnon-virtual-dtor... yes
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wold-style-cast... yes
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Weffc++... yes
checking if -Weffc++ should be enabled... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Woverloaded-virtual... yes
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wweak-vtables... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wdeprecated... yes
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wabstract-vbase-init... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Winconsistent-missing-destructor-override... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -fno-operator-names... yes
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant... yes
checking to enable LTO (link time optimization) build... no
checking for exp in -lm... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -fp-model precise... no
checking for C99 math functions... yes
checking for library containing sqrt... none required
checking for localeconv... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking jni.h usability... no
checking jni.h presence... no
checking for jni.h... no
checking whether to enable Java/JNI support... disabled
checking for mutexes... checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for pthread_mutexattr_settype in -lpthread... yes
checking whether PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE is declared... yes
enabled, pthread
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for SQLITE3... yes
checking for sqlite3... yes
using internal GTest.
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
 /bin/bash ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating cmake/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating include/Makefile
config.status: creating include/proj/Makefile
config.status: creating include/proj/internal/Makefile
config.status: creating test/Makefile
config.status: creating test/cli/Makefile
config.status: creating test/gie/Makefile
config.status: creating test/gigs/Makefile
config.status: creating test/unit/Makefile
config.status: creating man/Makefile
config.status: creating man/man1/Makefile
config.status: creating man/man3/Makefile
config.status: creating data/Makefile
config.status: creating jniwrap/Makefile
config.status: creating jniwrap/org.osgeo.proj/Makefile
config.status: creating jniwrap/org.osgeo.proj/org/Makefile
config.status: creating jniwrap/org.osgeo.proj/org/proj4/Makefile
config.status: creating test/googletest/Makefile
config.status: creating test/googletest/include/Makefile
config.status: creating test/googletest/include/gtest/Makefile
config.status: creating test/googletest/include/gtest/internal/Makefile
config.status: creating test/googletest/include/gtest/internal/custom/Makefile
config.status: creating test/googletest/src/Makefile
config.status: creating proj.pc
config.status: WARNING:  'proj.pc.in' seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
config.status: creating src/proj_config.h
config.status: src/proj_config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
Making all in include
make[1]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/include'
Making all in proj
make[2]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/include/proj'
Making all in internal
make[3]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/include/proj/internal'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/include/proj/internal'
make[3]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/include/proj'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/include/proj'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/include/proj'
make[2]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/include'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/include'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/include'
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/src'
(CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd .. && /bin/bash /software/proj.4/missing autoheader)
rm -f stamp-h1
touch proj_config.h.in
cd .. && /bin/bash ./config.status src/proj_config.h
config.status: creating src/proj_config.h
config.status: src/proj_config.h is unchanged
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/src'
Making all in man
make[1]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/man'
Making all in man1
make[2]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/man/man1'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/man/man1'
Making all in man3
make[2]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/man/man3'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/man/man3'
make[2]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/man'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/man'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/man'
Making all in data
make[1]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/data'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/data'
Making all in jniwrap
make[1]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/jniwrap'
Making all in org.osgeo.proj
make[2]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/jniwrap/org.osgeo.proj'
Making all in org
make[3]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/jniwrap/org.osgeo.proj/org'
Making all in proj4
make[4]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/jniwrap/org.osgeo.proj/org/proj4'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/jniwrap/org.osgeo.proj/org/proj4'
make[4]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/jniwrap/org.osgeo.proj/org'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/jniwrap/org.osgeo.proj/org'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/jniwrap/org.osgeo.proj/org'
make[3]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/jniwrap/org.osgeo.proj'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/jniwrap/org.osgeo.proj'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/jniwrap/org.osgeo.proj'
make[2]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/jniwrap'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/jniwrap'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/jniwrap'
Making all in cmake
make[1]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/cmake'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/cmake'
make[1]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4'
```

finally `make install`

```
Making install in include
make[1]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/include'
Making install in proj
make[2]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/include/proj'
Making install in internal
make[3]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/include/proj/internal'
make[4]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/include/proj/internal'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/include/proj/internal'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/include/proj/internal'
make[3]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/include/proj'
make[4]: Entering directory `/software/proj.4/include/proj'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/software/proj.4/include/proj'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 util.hpp metadata.hpp common.hpp crs.hpp datum.hpp coordinatesystem.hpp coordinateoperation.hpp io.hpp nn.hpp '/software/proj.4/include/proj'
/usr/bin/install: ‘util.hpp’ and ‘/software/proj.4/include/proj/util.hpp’ are the same file
/usr/bin/install: ‘metadata.hpp’ and ‘/software/proj.4/include/proj/metadata.hpp’ are the same file
/usr/bin/install: ‘common.hpp’ and ‘/software/proj.4/include/proj/common.hpp’ are the same file
/usr/bin/install: ‘crs.hpp’ and ‘/software/proj.4/include/proj/crs.hpp’ are the same file
/usr/bin/install: ‘datum.hpp’ and ‘/software/proj.4/include/proj/datum.hpp’ are the same file
/usr/bin/install: ‘coordinatesystem.hpp’ and ‘/software/proj.4/include/proj/coordinatesystem.hpp’ are the same file
/usr/bin/install: ‘coordinateoperation.hpp’ and ‘/software/proj.4/include/proj/coordinateoperation.hpp’ are the same file
/usr/bin/install: ‘io.hpp’ and ‘/software/proj.4/include/proj/io.hpp’ are the same file
/usr/bin/install: ‘nn.hpp’ and ‘/software/proj.4/include/proj/nn.hpp’ are the same file
make[4]: *** [install-projHEADERS] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/include/proj'
make[3]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/include/proj'
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/include/proj'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/software/proj.4/include'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

What I'm missing? Thank you

Comment: It looks like you are trying to install the software to the same directory that you're building it in (`--prefix=/software/proj.4`)

Comment: Yes, i would like to install the software exactly there. I would expect that it's possible without problems.

Comment: So in that case you don't really need to run `make install`...